# Web application is seemingly not running when deployed in websphere

Tags: websphere

I have a war file which I deployed and ran in tomcat. Then I deployed it in websphere from admin console. The status of the webapplication is seen as started along with the built-in web applications such as "ivtApp", "query", etc. Now from this link:

### Heading

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Frins_portnumber.html

It looks like the port number for web application is 9080 for http. I tried to run the application using the link:

http://{localhost}:9080/spring3HibernateMaven/index

(I am using "{" because this website didn't allow typing localhost)

the context root being spring3HibernateMaven. And I get page not found error in the browser. So I thought there must be something wrong with my web application. Hence I tried to run their web application:

http://{localhost}:9080/ivtApp

Which gives the same error. Even

http://{localhost}:9080/

gives the same error. I assume it should show something for this url as is shown from tomcat.

So how can I run the/any web application in websphere? FYI, I downloaded the latest version of websphere from their website.

Thanks

Comment: Did you install the WAR as part of an EAR? Did you install the application using the admin console or using wsadmin? If you go to Applications > Application Types > WebSphere enterprise applications > your-app > Context Root For Web Modules, you should be able to see the context root that was used for your application.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I deployed the war by selecting the new application. I used the correct contextpath, as I copied the one from running tomcat webapp and using it for the websphere webapp.

Comment: You can not assume the port you are using is 9080. You are looking at a document for WAS 6.0 and even then the port is reconfigurable. You said you downloaded the latest version of WebSphere, which is version 8.5, several major versions later. You need to figure out for sure what port you are using. Do you have access to the administrative console?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I created a third profile AppSrv03 and the port for this is 80. I opened http://localhost/ without a problem. However, my deployed war file is still not being shown in the browser with url http://localhost/spring3hibernate. Still no page found :(.

Comment: I meant the the port for the webserver of the profile is 80.

Answer (score 0):

ivtApp has context path "ivt", so you need to use host:9080/ivt

Btw, you can find context path setting in websphere\application control panel